# Convert multiple JSON File to CSV File, each in one column

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I have multiple JSON File that need to be converted in one CSV File

These are the example JSON code

tryout1.json

```
{
"Product":{
    "one":"Desktop Computer",
    "two":"Tablet",
    "three":"Printer",
    "four":"Laptop"
},
"Price":{
    "five":700,
    "six":250,
    "seven":100,
    "eight":1200
}}
```

tryout2.json

```
{
"Product":{
    "one":"dell xps tower",
    "two":"ipad",
    "three":"hp office jet",
    "four":"macbook"
},
"Price":{
    "five":500,
    "six":200,
    "seven":50,
    "eight":1000
}}
```

This is the python code that I wrote for converting those 2 json files

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.read_json('/home/mich/Documents/tryout.json')
print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_json('/home/mich/Documents/tryout2.json')
print(df2)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df.to_csv ('/home/mich/Documents/tryout.csv', index = None)

result = pd.read_csv('/home/mich/Documents/tryout.csv')
print(result)
```

But I didn't get the result I need. How can I print the first json file in one column (for both product and price) and the second in the next column? (view Image via Link)

The result I got

[[image]]

The result that I need

[[image: The result that I need]]

Comment: You want all products in one row and all prices in on row right? May be an example output would help on what you want to do.

Comment: Actually I wanted to post screenshot of the results, but I'm not sure if it's okay

Comment: it's okay to post screenshot of result. However code should always be in text.

Comment: okay, I have uploaded the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a combined column of product and prices then concat them.

I am using `axis = 1` since i want them to be combined side by side.(columns)
`axis = 0` will combine by rows.

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.read_json('/home/mich/Documents/tryout.json')
df1['product_price'] = df1['Product'].fillna(df1['Price'])

df2 = pd.read_json('/home/mich/Documents/tryout2.json')
df2['product_price'] = df2['Product'].fillna(df2['Price'])

pd.concat([df1['product_price'], df2['product_price']],axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I would also like to ask, how did you print the keys? The one-eight.

Comment: and what if the object in the json file are more than 2? Can I add another object with fillna()?

Comment: Hey, the one to eight is an index. it's created automatically when you load JSON. if you write to csv you should be able to see the data along with index.

Yes you can fill more then one column by adding one more fill na.

`df[d]  = df[a].fillna(df[b]).fillna(df[c])`

Comment: Since you haven't marked an answer as `answered` please consider making the post as answered/solved if it solves your question, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work